# fabric.js to show mirror image of canvas text

Tags: jquery, html, css, fabricjs

i am using `fabric.js` to write text on canva .later on click of button i want to show mirror image of text . is there any property in `fabric.js` which i can use to rotate text on canvas.

Please check , http://jsfiddle.net/BTh6A/9/

```
document.getElementById( 'btn' ).addEventListener( 'click', function (e) {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

    if ( !obj ) return;

    //here comes code to show mirror image

    obj.set( 'fill', '#FF0000' );
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this piece of code...I have edited it..

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    canvas.getActiveObject().set("angle", "-180").set('flipY', true);
    canvas.renderAll();

});
```

Comment: i dont want to rotate i want text to be flip... just like mirror

Comment: do you need an animation?

Comment: how can i managed object i layer ? i mean to say as we in css with z-index , what can i use here to bring element front and back?

Comment: These are the methods used canvas.sendBackwards(myObject)
canvas.sendToBack(myObject)
canvas.bringForward(myObject)
canvas.bringToFront(myObject)

Comment: can u plz check thi fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BTh6A/9/ , i want to change canvas text as soon as the text area changes

Comment: You want to get the text from text area and replace that with "sample" in your canvas?

Comment: yes , but not on change event , i want to write new text on canvas if no text is selected. and if text is selected than edit that text .

Answer (score 7):

```
function flipX() {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (obj) {
        obj.set('flipX', !obj.flipX);
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}

function flipY() {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (obj) {
        obj.set('flipY', !obj.flipY);
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
```