# oracle sql code for diaplaying mirror image of a text/column from the databse

Tags: oracle

I have referred to the previous question which was closed but similar issue. The answer provided was not good enough to solve my issue. please let me know if any other possible solutions for this.

The previous answer provided says that needs more insight. That is the reason I have asked a new question with exact requirement criteria. please note that this is not a duplicate of that.

I have a requirement where I need to display a text in the reverse as well as its mirror image. To be clear,

For example, if the column in the database reads " abcdefg",

the query output should be "bɟǝɐqɔp"

I have tried multiple ways but I was able to get only Reverse of the text as "gfedcba" but not the required output. please let me know the possible solution for this kind of requirement.

Comment: where are you using this output from the query ? can you provide a little more insight?

Comment: This sort of parlour trick is a display matter, and not something which we should expect a database query to handle.   [This thread offers a potential solution using JavaScript.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18482997/146325)

Comment: I am using the query on Oracle sql developer to get the mirror image of a data present in a particular column

Comment: I will be using this output on a MicroStrategy document

Answer (score 0):

I recall that this (or pretty much similar question) was asked back in October.  See this post, hopefully it will help you too:  [Sql code to create the Mirror image of the string in Oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912369/sql-code-to-create-the-mirror-image-of-the-string-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: I have referred to that post but the solution provided was not clear as I need to get the mirror image of the dynamic data from a column and the solution provided refers to the static text

Comment: @scr In that example, replace "t" with the word you need to mirror.  Make a working example out of it you must, else the force you are not yet ready to use.

Comment: can someone please help me get the mirror image of capital letters and numbers . I mean " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" and "0123456789". just as it would be enough. no need of any query as I am able to get them using the previous query